# How do I send an authorization key with my HTTP get request?

Tags: java, json, rest, httprequest

I'm trying to send a HTTP request to a REST API which requires and authorization key. My code works for REST API's that don't need authorization, but with this one, I only get error 403. I need help

The .setRequestProperty("Authorization", key) doesn't work. I've tried sending my key with "Bearer " +, but still nothing.

Here's the api: https://developer.clashroyale.com/#/getting-started

```
        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
        import java.net.MalformedURLException;
        import java.net.URL;

        public class Json {

            public static void main(String[] args) {

                try {

                    String key;
                    URL url = new URL("https://api.clashroyale.com/v1/players/%23PPCY9Y2J/upcomingchests");
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", key); 
                    if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
                    }

                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

                    String output;
                    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
                    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(output);
                    }

                    conn.disconnect();

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: Im pretty certain it is case sensetive. Use: **"authorization: Bearer <API token>"**. Essentially lowercase the 'a' and add Bearer.

Comment: If your key is a JWT, try using `conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + key);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you go to the documentation in https://developer.clashroyale.com/#/documentation and you select to "Try out" a request it shows an example request using curl. For example:

> curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header "**authorization: Bearer (token)**" 'https://api.clashroyale.com/v1/locations?limit=5'

There, you can see that "Authorization" is all lowercase and that you need "Bearer " before your key.

Therefore, change this line:

```
  conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", key);
```

For:

```
  conn.setRequestProperty("authorization", "Bearer " + key);
```